# Android graphics

Tags: android, graphic

I have a compass that's a subclass to the view class and my compass needle is a bitmap. Everytime the sensor changes the compass is invalidated and redrawn on the canvas, the rotation of the compass needle also changes. The problem i'm having is that when you see the compass needle rotating it's lagging a bit, basically poor fps. I'm guessing it's lagging because I'm redrawing a bitmap constantly instead of actually drawing, and wondering if the poor fps would go away if I used a surface view instead to draw on the canvas. Any tips on how to solve this the best way would be greatly appreciated. The image is 300x300 px.

Sensor in main activity:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float[] v = event.values;
    north = v[0];
    comp.setNorth(-v[0]);
}
```

Compass view:

```
public void setNorth(float n) {
    north_changed = true;
    north = n;
    invalidate();
}
```

Drawing bitmap:

```
private void drawCompass(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    if (north_changed == true) {
        canvas.rotate(north);
    }
    float maxwidth = (float) (canvasBitmap.getWidth() * Math.sqrt(2));
    float maxheight = (float) (canvasBitmap.getHeight() * Math.sqrt(2));
    float ratio = Math.min(w / maxwidth, h / maxheight);
    int width = (int) (canvasBitmap.getWidth() * ratio);
    int height = (int) (canvasBitmap.getHeight() * ratio);

    canvas.drawBitmap(compTexture, new Rect(0, 0, compTexture.getWidth(),
            compTexture.getHeight()), new Rect(-width / 2, -height / 2,
            width / 2, height / 2), facePaint);
    canvas.restore();

}
```

Comment: Can you post how you're drawing the bitmap? You shouldn't be experiencing performance issues if you're just drawing a rotated image especially one that is just 300x300 px. Using SurfaceView will NOT just make your performance problems go away.

Comment: What rate are you using when registering with the SensorManager? Try SENSOR_DELAY_GAME or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST. That may be where the lag is coming from.

Comment: Not helping to change rate, still same lagg.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SurfaceView` suits this task much better, it can render many more frames per second, you can also use `GLSurfaceView` to make sure everything is being rendered on the GPU.

Comment: SurfaceView didn't fix the lag, same as when I use a simple view.